# Retrieve additional columns in recursive CTE

Tags: postgresql, cte, recursive

This works as far as getting the amount of children a "thread" has but now I can't seem to get it to pull parent row columns. Parent rows have `parent_id is null`, trees can be any level deep.

I manage to do it with two separate queries but there has to be a way to just use one and get the count of the children:

```
with recursive all_comments as (
   select id, parent_id, id as root_id
   from comment
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, p.root_id
   from comment c
     join all_comments p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select root_id, count(*) as comment_count
from all_comments
group by root_id;
```

How would I pull `content` column from the parent `comment` in this fiddle?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/158ea/15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1

Include additional columns (just `content` in the example) in every iteration of the rCTE right away. You have to `GROUP BY` it (them) i the outer SELECT additionally.
Obviously, you don't want to count parents, so join the first level of children right away:

```
WITH recursive tree AS (
   SELECT p.id AS root_id, c.id, p.content
   FROM   comment p
   LEFT   JOIN comment c ON c.parent_id = p.id
   WHERE  p.parent_id IS NULL

   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.root_id, c.id, p.content
   FROM   tree p
   JOIN   comment c ON c.parent_id = p.id
)
SELECT root_id, content, count(id) AS comment_count
FROM   tree
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1;
```

To preserve parents without any children use `LEFT JOIN` in the base `SELECT` of the rCTE. Consequently, use `count(id)` in the outer `SELECT` to ignore NULL values produced by this.

#### Option 2

For very deep trees or big additional columns it may be cheaper to just retrieve IDs in the rCTE and join to the table `comment` once more in the outer `SELECT` to retrieve more columns:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
   SELECT p.id AS root_id, c.id
   FROM   comment p
   LEFT   JOIN comment c ON c.parent_id = p.id
   WHERE  p.parent_id IS NULL

   UNION ALL
   SELECT p.root_id, c.id
   FROM   tree p
   JOIN   comment c ON c.parent_id = p.id
   )
SELECT p.*, c.content  -- add more columns?
FROM  (
   SELECT root_id, count(id) AS comment_count
   FROM   tree
   GROUP  BY 1  -- cheaper ...
   ) p
JOIN   comment c ON c.id = p.root_id  -- ... but additional join
ORDER  BY p.root_id;
```

Your fiddle had two errors. Consider this fixed [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a8a2b/11).

Comment: The only problem is that its not pulling the content column which is what I was trying to figure out but thank you! Anyway you can edit it?

Comment: @Jake: I added the column.

Answer (score 2):

Your fiddle does not open, so I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you have and what you want, but I'd venture to guess you need to join back to `comment` on `id`, something like this:

```
with recursive all_comments as (
   select id, parent_id, id as root_id
   from comment
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, p.root_id
   from comment c
     join all_comments p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select a.root_id, a.comment_count, com.content from 
(select root_id, count(*) as comment_count
from all_comments
group by root_id) as a
inner join
comment as com
 on a.root_id = com.id and com.parent_id is null;
```

Comment: Fiddle was down, but I tried your query, doesn't work? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/158ea/24 I'm trying to pull the content column for the parent row

Comment: @Jake Apparently, `all` is a reserved word; replace it with something else. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/158ea/26/0

Comment: The root IDs are those that have no parent – therefore `and com.parent_id is null` is redundant.